# regex in c# to extract page.com/users/(this)/xxxxx/

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've been trying to solve this for last two hours but it just doesnt work :(

I have downloaded html code of one web page and then I have removed all double white spaces and all new lines so the whole code is one line string.

And then I have to extract one piece of data from it

page.com/users/(this)/xxxxx/.....

```
match = Regex.Match(htmlCode, "page.com/users/(.*)/xxxxx/");
string user = match.Groups[1].ToString();
```

but it doesn't work, I always get (this)/xxxxx/ + the rest of html code.

Anyone know why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of the greedy `(.*)`, use `([^/]*)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `.*` is matching everything after that, including the `/xxxxx/` portion.

Comment: Hmmm, Why would it match /xxxxx/.. shouldn't it mean any character till /xxxxx/, BTW this regex worked till I converted all html code to on line (cant change that)

Comment: `.*` will match anything, but a new line character, which is why you didn't experience this until you put everything on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Specify .* more specifically like [^/]+ meaning there has to be something there and it can be anything but a /

Answer (score 0):

try

```
match = Regex.Match(htmlCode, "page.com/users/([^/]*)/xxxxx/");
string user = match.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try `page.com/users/([^/]*)/xxxxx/`